# Unit testing an event

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I'm new to C# and WPF. I'm following a tutorial and I found this code which contains a unit test with an event can you explain it to me:

```
[TestClass]
class ObservableObjectTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void PropertyChangedEventHandlerIsRaised()
    {
        var obj = new SubObservableObject();

        bool raised = false;

        obj.PropertyChanged += (Sender, e) =>
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(e.PropertyName == "ChangedProperty");
                raised = true;

            };
    }
}
```

Comment: That code is not complete. You never change the property in the test so the test does nothing.

Comment: thank you I will take them into consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Scott Chamberlain said in the comments, your example code doesn't represent a real test case.  A minimum test case would be something like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class ObservableObjectTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void PropertyChangedEventHandlerIsRaised() {
        // Create the object to test (sut)
        var sut = new SubObservableObject();

        //  Create a flag to monitor if event handler has fired
        //  set it to false initially, since it hasn't...
        bool raised = false;

        // Register our test event handler, with the PropertyChanged
        // event.
        sut.PropertyChanged += (Sender, e) => {
                // Check that when the event handler is called
                // it is for the 'ChangedProperty'
                Assert.IsTrue(e.PropertyName == "ChangedProperty");
                // Set our flag to indicate that event was triggered
                raised = true;
            };

        // Actually perform the test, by setting 'ChangedProperty' to 
        // a new value.  This will fire the code above if it works.
        sut.ChangedProperty = "newValue";

        // Validate that our raised flag has been set to true, indicating
        // that our test event handler was triggered.
        Assert.AreEqual(true, raised);
    }
}
```

Note, in order for the above to work, I've assumed a lot about the code that is being tested.  Essentially, I've assumed that the code being tested looks a lot like this:

```
public class SubObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string ChangedProperty {
        get { return _changedProperty; }
        set {
            _changedProperty = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ChangedProperty" ));
        }
    }

    public string _changedProperty;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
};
```

As has been mentioned in the comments, this is a minimum example code to get the test you are asking about to work.  The tutorial you are following *should* have additional tests to help validate their code.  The following test would be enough to force the PropertyChanged event to be tested for null.

```
[TestMethod]
public void PropertyCanChangeWithNoEventHandlersSet() {
    var sut = new SubObservableObject();

    // The next line will throw a null exception with the minimal
    // code written above, since there is no check for 
    // if(null != PropertyChanged) before invoking the PropertyChanged
    // event.
    sut.ChangedProperty = "newValue";

    Assert.AreEqual("newValue", sut.ChangedProperty);
}
```

In a *real* code base, it's likely that this check and invocation will have been re-factored into a single function that is invoked from all properties in the class.

Depending on the version of C# being targeted, it's also possible that this method automatically detects the name of the property being changed, using [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx) so that it doesn't have to be explicitly provided.  This would result in code like this [from microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
// This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
// The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
// parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

With this method being invoked by each individual property:

```
public string ChangedProperty {
    get { return _changedProperty; }
    set {
            _changedProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain, I've amended the expected code with your feedback to make it simpler.

Comment: Though arguably a fine answer, you have arguably spent more effort explaining _what `SubObservableObject` is_ (the code under test; due to the OP not posting any code on is somewhat hypothetical) rather than _what the unit test code does_ as per the OP's question _"I'm following a tutorial and I found this code which contains a **unit test** with an event can you **explain it** to me"_.  However I agree the OP's question is incomplete and therein perhaps lays the problem.  Code comments are nice but perhaps explain the unit test block in plain english.  Good luck!

Comment: In fact, the tutorial I'm following contains more than one example. Just I was disturbing with the Event. Thank you